# Can't locate Magento 1.9 cache anywhere on FTP. Any ideas how to find it?

Tags: magento-1.9, cache

Can't locate Magento 1.9 cache anywhere on FTP. Any ideas how to find it?

Of course I've already checked the usual places like /var/cache but it's just not there. Any ideas on how to find it?

Answer (score 0):

There is no proper permission in /var/cache folder it is not stored in Magento root path /var/cache. it will store in /tmp/magento/var/cache. Please check it.

Hope it will helpful for you.

Comment: That directory exists on my server, but there is nothing in it. Still trying to find where cache files are stored.

Comment: any other cache you are installed in your server? or what are folder are available in tmp?

Answer (score 0):

## 1

You should first verify if cache is enabled at all.
If it is, but your hosting for some reason does not allow writing in your applicatios ./var directory (as it was mentioned before), the cache will be saved in /tmp

## 2

If it is enabled, yet, not saved anywhere on file system, see if you are using Redis for caching. (see `local.xml`)

Disclaimer: If you use some hosting that `sets up environment for you` and you don't really know what's there, might as well be that it is configured to use Redis

The usual side effect of Redis is that general folders like `var/cache/`, `var/full_page` are created but have no content at all